# Trying to overwrite memory at specific address

Tags: objective-c, memory, pointers, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

I realize that trying to tamper with memory from another application or from the OS is considered bad programming.

However, I do not understand Objective C, and **I need to read 25 bytes from a fixed memory address into a variable, and then replace those 25 bytes with a different set**.

I'm terrible with pointers and with what all the * and the & and the @ symbols mean.

I am attempting this in Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), using XCode 4.4.1.

I've tried things like:

```
char *myPtr = (char*) 0x7FFA8000 // just an example, not the real memory address
char myString[] = *myPtr
```

Comment: I don't know much about iOS specifics, but I doubt that you have access to the physical memory to get a fixed location. You will have access to your process memory.

Comment: If you need to access some particular place in "main memory", there *may* be an OSx API for doing this, for privileged methods accessing certain specific areas of system storage.  But it would be an OSx API, not something Objective-C specific.

Comment: @PaulR gives you the code to do that. But the real question is: what is your definition of "fixed memory address"? Because there's no such a thing unless you are executing code at the kernel level. The best you may get is a non-fixed virtual address that is mapped to a fixed address. And you need some special kernel API to get that (not even sure there are any public APIs that do that on Os X as there's no business for an userlevel app in such a thing).

Comment: Yeah, I've confirmed it doesn't work once the OS is loaded. But I can write to the specific memory addresses I need to change BEFORE the OS is loaded in the EFI Shell (with the native mm command of the EFI Shell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's 25 characters you might do it like this:

```
char *myPtr = (char*) 0x7FFA8000; // pointer to arbitrary memory address
char myString[26];                // buffer to copy data to
memcpy(myString, myPtr, 25);      // do the copy
myString[25] = '\0';              // make sure string is terminated
```

To write back to the arbitrary address:

```
char *myPtr = (char*) 0x7FFA8000; // pointer to arbitrary memory address
char myString[26];                // buffer to copy data from
memcpy(myPtr, myString, 25);      // do the copy
```

Note that in both cases you're just accessing memory within your own process's virtual address space - you're not reading/writing the memory of the OS or another process.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I can pull this off is to write the new bytes to the memory address before the OS loads (in the EFI Shell).  This does work, but due to a bug in the implementation of the EFI Shell on my system, I can't script it.  I have to manually type the mm command and parameters in the EFI shell on every boot (before the OS loads).